# How can I keep my wooden kitchen sink utility platform from slipping forward in the sink?

Tags: wood, kitchens

I could use some ideas on this.

This is a device I use to increase my counter space. It is coated in of 3 coats of Polyurethane. It is angled downward to drain off water.

I put things on it like bowls, glasses, etc.
[image]

How can I keep the board from sliding forward?
[image]

Comment: you could put a suction cup in front of each side "leg", which would get in the way of a forward slide.

Comment: I might look for some 1/2 inch suction cups. I thought of attaching some sand paper to the bottom edges, but that might scratch the stainless steel sink.

Answer (score 5):

Self adhesive rubber weather stripping. It should be just a few dollars at the hardware store for a 10 foot roll of half inch wide. It's reasonably weather resistant so it will stay okay for a while, and when it starts to fall apart you can use the next two feet off the roll. Stick it on the underside where your device rests on the sink. It will grip the sink and prevent sliding.

Answer (score 5):

Anti-slip bumper pads on the bottom of the board where it sits on the sink should do the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I like to make super cheap and effective non-skid "feet" using low-temp hot glue. It tends to be more pliable (rubbery) than hi-temp glue. These feet are waterproof and tend to stick much better than the pressure-sensitive adhesive used on press-on sticker feet/pads.

For the feet I make, I put a dime-size dab of glue on the bottom of the "thing", then press it down onto wax paper while the glue is still warm. This leaves a very flat bottom on the foot. I'm thinking that just running a bead along the edge would work for you, just try to keep it even, or if you warm your board up ahead of time with a hair dryer, you could probably do the wax paper trick to make sure it's nice flat and even.

Comment: I have a variable temp glue gun. The glue sticks that I have work great with wood. I will have to see if it sticks to my urethane covered wood. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to keep the board from slipping.

I cleaned the sink and hot glued the board to the sink under the small block of wood.

I also glued strips of "knobby' rubber to the front of the board on the underside.

It further slows down any forward motion.

I won't be using the right side of the sink and I can reach under the board if something falls off the board.

See picture.

[image]